# How to set Hyperlink.Foreground with a Setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, setter

I'm trying to set `Hyperlink.Foreground` with a setter. The setter is going to be within a `MultiDataTrigger`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<Setter Property="Hyperlink.Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
```

This has no effect

```
<Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}" x:Key="greenHyperlink">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen"/>
</Style>
```

does work, but

```
<Setter Property="Hyperlink.Style" Value="{StaticResource greenHyperlink}"/>
```

Throws up and exception.

How do I set hyperlink color with a setter?

Comment: aren't you having a typo? is Hyperlink or Hyperline?

Comment: yeah. I've typed that into tho question box. does not change the thing that .net does not allow to modify style via setter

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the line below :

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#........"/>
```

Update:

Please have a look at this post already answered this might help you

[Changing Hyperlink foreground without losing hover color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252889/changing-hyperlink-foreground-without-losing-hover-color)

Comment: setting property Foreground in Hyperlink.Style works. But I need to somehow set it from the outside

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the Style of the HyperLink, why not just :

```
<HyperLink Style="{StaticResource greenHyperLink}"/>
```

Or you could just try this instead :

```
<Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}" x:Key="greenHyperlink">
     <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource greenHyperLink}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: which one? what is the exception you are having?